# Setting multiple object attributes at once

Tags: python, variables, attributes

Is there a way to set multiple attributes of the same object on a single line, similarly to the way one assigns values to multiple variables?

If I can write

```
a,b,c=1,2,3
```

I would like to have something like

```
someObject.(a,b,c)=1,2,3
```

Having the same effect as

```
someObject.a=1
someObject.b=2
someObject.c=3
```

Comment: I would love to see this as syntax sugar. `someObject.(a,b,c)=1,2,3` or `(obj1,obj2).a=2,3`. Or even `(obj1,obj2).(a,b)=(a1,b1),(a2,b2)`. Don't thinks it's going to happen.

Answer (score 24):

```
def setattrs(_self, **kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(_self, k, v)
```

Use this function like this:

```
setattrs(obj,
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    #...
)
```

You can also define this function on class, but that would be less generic (i.e. apply only to that class instances).

Another answer mentions `__dict__.update` and it can be rewritten to get rid of quotes: `obj.__dict__.update(a=1, b=2)`, however i would not recommend using this method: it doesn't work with properties and it might be hard to notice if you migrate from simple attributes to properties. Basically, `__dict__` is "hidden" attribute, implementation detail, which you shouldn't use unless you really want to change implementation in some way.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you can do the same with object attributes as with other variables:

```
someObject.a, someObject.b, someObject.c = 1,2,3
```

Not sure if that is already what you have in mind. If you want to update arbitrary attributes (e.g. in a function) then you could exploit the fact that Python objects store their attributes in a dict, which supports the [update()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method:

```
someObject.__dict__.update({"a":1, "b":2, "c":3})
```

However, this should only be done with care! If one would offer this in a function any attribute of someObject can be changed with that function and even new attributes can be inserted!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` to update the attributes of an object with a dictionary of attributes and values.

```
attrs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

map(lambda item: setattr(someObject, *item), attrs.iteritems())
```

In Python 3, you need to surround the `map` call with a list and convert `iteritems` to `items` like so.

```
list(map(lambda item: setattr(someObject, *item), attrs.items()))
```

Comment: with `map`, you can't do this in python 3 since map returns an iterator. You may wrap it in `tuple()` or `list`

Answer (score 1):

```
attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]
for attr, val in zip(attributes, values):
    setattr(obj, attr, val)
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but is not more elegant and neither more readable than the three-line version above. What I would like to find out is whether Python has some syntactic sugar that can simplify attribute setting.