# call for multiple attributes of an object sequentially in one line?

Tags: python, class, object

Just a passing query...

say i have some **class**:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade, school=None):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.school = school

    def enroll(self, school):
        self.school = school
```

I know that I can call attributes of an object like so:

```
x = Student("John Doe", 12)
print( x.grade )
print( x.name )
```

but is there a way I could call multiple attributes sequentially from an object by **only referencing to the object once**?

maybe something like:

```
x.(grade,name)
```

would return:

```
12 John Doe
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting multiple object attributes at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212361/setting-multiple-object-attributes-at-once)

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: @AMC I was just wondering if there was a more minimal way to do it instead of referencing the object every time. just a passing query

Comment: What should `x.(grade,name)` *evaluate to*? A tuple of items? In that case, you can do `x.grade, x.name`.

Comment: To simply answer your question, you can't do that in Python (nor in any other language I know of). The *closest* thing I can think to this is Destructuring Assignment in JavaScript, but it's only for assignments.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was wondering if there's any way to do it with only referencing to the object once

Comment: Note that our topic guidelines ask for **practical** questions. Requests that something be a one-liner often devolve into code golf -- academic exercises that have no resemblance to robust, idiomatic, maintainable code, and which are thus not practical in any kind of real-world use.

Comment: is the `12` a number or a string in the result?, just implement a method with a `*args` parameter and walk this list with `getattr` and join the results

Comment: well in this case the practicality might be to pass a list of attributes without having to iterate through them w/ a loop. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @rioV8 12 is an integer as defined in `x = Student("John Doe", 12)`

Comment: Nope. I mean, you can write a function that does that for you if you need to do it a lot. Indeed, there is a built-in function factory for that, `operator.attrgetter`, but you shouldn't use that like `operator.attrgetter('grade', 'name')(x)`. Its mostly to pass to higher-order functions, like `map`

Comment: @user2089810, some of the macros in Clojure's standard library can be used for this, so there's _one_ language with something equivalent-ish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga honestly, that's close enough, i was mainly looking at the educational side of it all, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(lambda i: (i.grade,i.name))(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

#### No syntax for this purpose is built into the Python language.