# Updating an instance of an object with the __init__ method

Tags: python, oop, memory-management

#### Reusing the `__init__` method to change attributes' values

*Python 3.10 on Windows 64bit*

Let's say I have a class that has an `update` method which calls the `__init__` method.
The `update` method is created to avoid multiple line assignments of the attributes.

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
         self.name = name
         self.age = age

     def update(self, **attributes):
         self.__init__(**attributes)
```

**Object instantiation:**

```
p = Person(name="Alex", age=32)
print(p.name, p.age)

>> Alex 32
```

**Object reference before:**

```
print(p)

>> <__main__.Person object at 0x0000028B4ED949A0>
```

**Calling for the update method:**

```
p.update(name="Sam", age=80)
print(p.name, p.age)

>> Sam 80
```

**Object reference after:**

```
print(p)

>> <__main__.Person object at 0x0000028B4ED949A0>
```

**Clearly, the reference hasn't changed!**

##### Is this safe? Is there a chance where the object reference in memory gets changed?

Obviously the actual use of this is for large objects that has multiple parameters and get frequently modified at once as internal reactions. Some parameters are optional and don't get modified.

*If I don't do it like this, I would have to write a cascade of if-else statements which I don't want to. :)*

Comment: No, there is absolutely no chance of that. A method cannot change the object's identity like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__`, unlike `__new__`, doesn't deal with memory references at all. `self` is already a valid object produced by `__new__` which `__init__` initializes.

You can do it the other way round for clarity:

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
         # Signal to whoever will read your code
         # that the class is supposed to have these attributes
         self.name = None
         self.age = None
         self.update(name=name, age=age)

     def update(self, name: str, age: int):
         self.name = name
         self.age = age
```

Now `__init__` isn't called by other methods, so no confusion arises.

Comment: This is one of my previous approaches to the problem. But you can see there is unnecessary redundancy (assigning None then calling update).

Comment: Well, you don't _have_ to assign `None` since any method can create new instance attributes (any method can do `self.random_attribute = 42`). Anyway, Python manages memory automatically, so most of the time you don't need to even know that memory management exists or what stuff like `0x0000028B4ED949A0` is. Objects don't get randomly reallocated. Even if they did, you can be sure that `self` always refers to the proper object.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to ForceBru's answer if wanted

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def update(self, **attributes):
        for attribute, value in attributes.items():
            if hasattr(self,attribute):
                setattr(self, attribute, value)
            else:
                raise AttributeError(f'{self.__name__} has no attribute: {attribute}')
        
x = Person(name='Henry',age=12)
print(f'name={x.name}, age={x.age}')
x.update(name='Joe')
print(f'name={x.name}, age={x.age}')
x.update(name='Kyle',age=20)
print(f'name={x.name}, age={x.age}')
```

gives output

```
name=Henry, age=12
name=Joe, age=12
name=Kyle, age=20
```

this is just template (you may have other specific behavior that want for example dont want users to overwrite attributes start with `_`, etc).

I will say ultimately ForceBru's is nice in terms of linters, intellisense, etc, so can use what works for you

Comment: or can take a more functional approach like in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212361/setting-multiple-object-attributes-at-once)